# Display clicked image in different div Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have some images. When an image is clicked I want to get that image displayed in a different div. Been struggling with how to solve this. This is what I've got so far.

```
<% @user.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag((image.url), :id => 'test')%>
<% end %>
```

js.coffee

```
$('#test').click ->
  val = $(this).attr("src")
  alert val // /assets/image.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since you have an array of images, you should use `class` than `id`.

```
<% @user.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag((image.url), :class => 'test')%>
<% end %>
```

And in JS, you will bind click event to image with class 'test'.

```
$(".test").click ->
  val = $(this).attr("src")
  $("#showDiv").html "<img src=\"" + val + "\" />"
```

Where `#showDiv` is the id of the div which you want the image to be shown.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but the image is just visible for a second and then disappears. How can I get it to stay after .click?

Comment: Solved it with return false. Thanks!